# Objective-C playground?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there any sort of Mac app, Web app, or others like [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for Objective-C/Cocoa purposes?

Comment: Mac App: Isn't that pretty much XCode?

Comment: Xcode does many things, but live rapid prototyping is not really its forte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely the same, but look into F-Script: http://www.fscript.org/

It lets you rapid-prototype and experiment. You can also hook it into existing apps very easily. It has been invaluable for me for certain types of UI debugging.

Answer (score 3):

I've also found [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/) to be quite handy for boilerplate app generation and one-click console running to try language snippets out.  Available on the AppStore at a price.

Answer (score 3):

I created playgrounds for Objective-C on top of code injection, so you can experiment with normal iOS simulator, it's [open source on GitHub](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/KZPlayground)

[Video showing them in action](https://vimeo.com/109757619)